# How to solve: `could not open extension control file "/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/share/postgresql@13/extension/postgis.control`?

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, postgis

I have installed postgresql 13 and postgis on macOS 13.5.2 (Apple M2) by using:

```
brew update
brew install postgresql@13
brew services start postgresql@13

brew install postgis
```

But, I have been facing problems when trying to restore databases from .sql files using pgAdmin4. I got this log:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: could not open extension control file "/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/share/postgresql@13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Also, when entering psql terminal by `psql -U postgres` and trying to execute `create extension postgis;`, I got:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/share/postgresql@13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Further info:

- When using: `which psql`, I got:
  `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/bin/psql`
- When using: `which pg_config`, I got:
  `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/bin/pg_config`
- When using: `brew info postgis`, I got:

```
==> postgis: stable 3.3.4 (bottled), HEAD
Adds support for geographic objects to PostgreSQL
https://postgis.net/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgis/3.3.4_1 (725 files, 46.2MB) *
```

- When using: `brew info postgresql@13`, I got:

```
==> postgresql@13: stable 13.12 (bottled) [keg-only]
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@13/13.12 (3,244 files, 43MB)
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-08-29 at 10:13:22
```

Can someone suggest to me how to solve this?

Comment: The PostGIS installation does not match your PostgreSQL installation - is installs the software in the wrong directory. See if you can find a PostGIS installation package that matches your PostgreSLQ v13 installation. Otherwise, you can install from source.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue when I was trying to create postgis extension, and was using Postgresql@15 with Postgis@3.3.4_1, turns out it's a versions issue.

I also had Postgresql@14 installed, so I had to stop my current postgresql@15 service with

```
brew services stop postgresql@15
```

and started postgresql@14 with brew services

```
brew services start postgresql@14
```

and finally creating/using the postgis extension was not met with that error.